# rails cant load template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error when trying to start a new project -

```
bash-3.2$ rails new cards -dmysql
The template [/Users/rails/template] could not be loaded. Error: Could not find "/Users/rails/template" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
/Users/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates
```

Confusingly the user is called "rails". Regardless of which path I'm in it gives the error $path/template could not be loaded....

Answer (score 2):

nktokyo - were you ever able to resolve this issue? I am seeing the same thing.

I am using Ruby v3.0.5, RVM and Ruby v1.8.7. (get error with bot p174 & p334)

The error is only generated when I apply the -dmysql to the rails new command.

---

Just discovered that if you apply `--database=mysql`, the error is avoided. I don't have an explanation for why, but hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: Just discovered that if you apply --database=mysql, the error is avoided. I don't have an explanation for why, but hope that helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

use rvm for installing ruby and rails http://rvm.io/ for OSX / Windows users there is http://railsinstaller.org

Comment: I am using it. Installing following the railstutorial.org guide.