# Rails Error: Could not find "/home/me/3/template" in any of your source paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does this error mean, I don't recognize it?

```
me@michael-laptop:~/3$ rails new zzz -dmysql

The template [/home/me/3/template] could not be loaded. 
Error: Could not find "/home/me/3/template" in any of your source paths. 
Your current source paths are: 
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates
```

I can do `me@michael-laptop:~/3$ rails new zzz`

no problem

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5399956/308315  ... Their solution was to use `--database=mysql` instead of `-dmysql`

Comment: or try with a space? `rails new zzz -d mysql` ??

Comment: Surya, that helped.  See myupdate for more info.

Comment: if you've found the solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it. Much more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the ruby version (1.8.7 vs 1.9.2) right was also a factor here.  I use rvm for that.
This along with Surya's helpful comment gives the answer.

So here are the rails 2 and rails 3 syntax:

Rails 2 `rails zzz -d mysql`

Rails 3 `rails new zzz -d mysql`